# Summarising data from when groups are not the same

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
    group = c("S_1","G_1","G_2","G_3","M_1","M_2","G_1","G_2","S_1","S_2","M_1","M_2"),
    CODE = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1)
)
```

> ```
>    ID group CODE
> 1   1   S_1    0
> 2   1   G_1    1
> 3   1   G_2    0
> 4   1   G_3    0
> 5   1   M_1    1
> 6   1   M_2    1
> 7   2   G_1    0
> 8   2   G_2    1
> 9   2   S_1    0
> 10  2   S_2    0
> 11  2   M_1    1
> 12  2   M_2    1
> ```

I would like to summarize the CODE column such that for each ID, I end up with one row:

> ```
>     ID CODE
> 1   1  100,11,0
> 2   2  01,11,00
> ```

for `ID==1`, I would like to paste `G_1,G_2,G_3` without a delimiter (in numeric order). Same goes for `M_1` and `M_2` and then `S_1`. Lastly, I would like to add the summarized `G, M, and S` into one row separating these by a comma (in alphabetic order).

I could potentially remove the numbers and do `group_by(group) %>% summarise(CODE=paste(CODE, collapse=""))` for the first step. Though I would like the final string to be in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::separate` to get data in `group` in different columns based on delimiter (`_`) and then `summarise` first by `ID` and `group1` and then by `ID` to get one string for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ID,group) %>%
  tidyr::separate(group, into = c('group1', 'group2'), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID, group1) %>%
  summarise(CODE = paste(CODE, collapse = "")) %>%
  summarise(CODE = toString(CODE))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID CODE      
#  <dbl> <chr>     
#1     1 100, 11, 0
#2     2 01, 11, 00
```

---

Without using `separate`, we can remove everything after `"_"` and use it as group.

```
df %>%
  arrange(ID,group) %>%
  mutate(group = sub('_.*', '', group)) %>%
  group_by(ID, group) %>%
  summarise(CODE = paste(CODE, collapse = "")) %>%
  summarise(CODE = toString(CODE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Order the dataframe and genericise the group vector: 

ordered_df <- within(df[with(df, order(ID, group)), ], {
  group <- gsub("_.*", "", group)
  }
)

# Summarise the dataframe: 

aggregate(CODE~ID, do.call("rbind", lapply(split(ordered_df, paste0(ordered_df$ID, ordered_df$group)),
             function(x){
                 data.frame(ID = unique(x$ID), CODE = paste0(x$CODE, collapse = ""))
                }
              )
            ), paste, collapse = ",")
```